# On changing the orientation of ion-range.The knob is not working smoothly in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am looking for the range bar which is rotated 90 deg(vertically). When it is rotated vertically I am unable to select to the respective step points in the range bar. Whenever the knob is tried to move is it not moving to the desired step points. The touch functionality is not smooth.

The following is the css: 
       I am rotating the component using the following CSS. After applying this css property **transform: rotate(-90deg)** the ion-range step is not properly working in the UI(i.e.,The range slider is not moving properly).If any alternate solution apart from this css property I am open for your suggessions.

```
ion-range {       [The following has the final Rangebar I am looking for ][1]
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: relative;
}
```

The following is the html

```
<ion-range min="1" max="5" step="1" snaps="true" color="primary"
 [(ngModel)]="abc"></ion-range>
```

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aODnC.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its not going to be addressed until v.4 - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12713